# How to configure specific G4 events as an attribute in HTML?

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In the "Create Events" area of ​​google analytics I created the following event:

[image]

Then in the HTML I inserted it like this:

```
<a GA-TRACKER="HEADER-SEND-EMAIL"></a>
<a GA-TRACKER="SECTION-SEND-EMAIL"></a>
```

What I intend to do is map the click on two buttons that exist on the site for sending e-mail and find out if the click was on the main or secondary button.

Is this right?
Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: What made you think GA-TRACKER parameter would make any difference?

Comment: Due to my creation of it in Google Analytics, as shown in the image. But from your speech, it seems I did it wrong, could you help me with an answer to my case?

Comment: I asked just in case you forgot to mention you have an elaborate event listener for all clicks that have that parameter set, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

GA's functionality for new events creation is quite weak. It only allows you to make events based on the existing data. It won't allow you to influence the data capturing.

What you need to do is implement separate tracking for the things you want to track. The classical way of doing it is via GTM. It's also can be done by deploying event listeners for the clicks you want and dispatching custom events via the gtag.js library.

Also please consider not adding random attributes to your elements. If you feel you need custom attributes, read more on [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).